# My (String).split("="); isnt working?

Tags: java, file, hashmap

I wanted to make a string to a String[] but it isnt working how i wanted it to work! My code:

```
    public static void get(HashMap<String, String> saves, File file) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    if (!file.exists()){
        return;
    }
    InputStreamReader reader;
    reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-16");
    String r = null;
    String[] s;
    BufferedReader bufreader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    while((r=bufreader.readLine()) != null){
        s = r.split("=");
        if (s.length < 2){
            System.out.println(s.length);
            System.out.println(s[0]);
            return;
        }
        saves.put(s[0].toString(), s[1].toString());
        s = null;
    }
}
```

And also when i tell it to println the String to the console

```
System.out.println(s.length);
System.out.println(s[0]);
```

it just prints:

```
1
??????????????????
 - 
 -
```

What it should be reading (What is in the file):

```
1=welcome
2=hello
3=bye
4=goodbye
```

So i want it to put the values in to the hashmap:

```
saves.put("1", "welcome");
saves.put("2", "hello");
saves.put("3", "bye");
saves.put("4", "goodbye");
```

but the **s = e.split("=")** is not splitting it is making the String to "?????????"
Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your data file is UTF-16?

Comment: Well its a .txt file im new with files in java but writing in to the file works perfect!

Comment: can you paste a couple lines of the file in your original question?

Comment: All the lines in the file is
1=welcome
2=hello
...

Comment: "UTF-16" I don't think that is right

Comment: Sort of echoing David, have you tried UTF-8 instead?

Comment: @3kings what do i use for .txt files?

Comment: Umm how about try not sending it that parameter. or just do "UTF-8"

Comment: UTF-8 doesnt work either i just tried and it just printed
"-
-"
and on the end when i run the void i have made that it prints the setted HashMap and it just print that ^^

Comment: @Rof  Why not just send the `BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))`

Comment: @3kings just did that the same thing but i just found out why it is printing the "- -" its because i did the Sting.join((the hashmap that i used), " - ");
So it isnt reading anything that means it just "null" or ""

Comment: This is probably not a problem with splitting a String. Have you tried to printout `r` before splitting? I think this may be a great time to look into debugging!

Comment: Yes, i just did that and it prints out what i wanted, it prints what is in the file!

Comment: There is no need to use `s[0].toString()`. Each element of s _is_ a string so just use 
`saves.put(s[0], s[1] );`

Comment: @FredK i just did that still the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're using the wrong encoding.
Your input file is not really `UTF-16`, as the Java code expects it.

I saved your example data in a file, and the result was similarly broken.

The default encoding on my system is UTF-8, so I changed the encoding of the file with the command:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 orig.txt > converted.txt
```

When using your program on `converted.txt`,
it produces the expected output.

It also produces the expected output if I use `orig.txt`,
and make this simple change in your program:

```
reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");
```

You can either make sure the file is UTF-16 encoded,
and if not, convert it,
or use the correct encoding when you create the `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: If the input file needs to be UTF-16, then convert it. If you don't want to convert it, then find its encoding, and change the Java code appropriately. UTF-8 in my answer is just an example, you need to adjust to your use case and system.

Comment: I have changed it so that it doesnt use any UTF but before i made it to UTF-8 and the problem returned but it might be a problem with the r.split("="); ?